# Java Dates - What's the correct class to use?

Tags: java, android

So the whole Java Date/Calendar/GregorianCalendar thing is obviously a joke.  What's the right Date class to use?

**Edit:** Building an SDK for third parties on Android where the application needs to provide a date

**More Edit:** Things that make this so obviously a joke:

- 99% of Date is deprecated
- Date's Year is offset from 1900
- Date's Month is zero-indexed while day is one-indexed
- Dates are mutable
- You're supposed to use a Calendar to create a date...
- ... except you really have to use a GregorianCalendar

  - Do a significant percent of developers want to use a different calendar?
- Calendar.getTime() returns a Date
- There's no Date math (like how far apart are two dates in years)

  - Messing with milliseconds since epoch doesn't count
- You can't chain parts together to get an expression (like the date one year ago today)
- Probably more stuff

Comment: I'm upvoting cause I agree (sadly) that the whole Calendar mishmash is a huge pile of doo.  I end up using just Date, or even System.currentTimeMillis(), far too often.

Comment: It's no joke!  It's just the sad state of affairs of the date APIs in Java...

Comment: See also: [What's wrong with Java Date & Time API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/642706)

Comment: @BasilBourque I’m not sure resurrecting such an old question is worth the effort.

Comment: @DaveNewton By "resurrecting" do you mean my linking to related Question, or answering this one? Either way, "ignore old Questions" must be a new policy on Stack Overflow, so please point me to documentation on that. Previously this site handed out awards for new activity on old questions.

Comment: @BasilBourque Just because you get a shiny for tickling old questions doesn't mean it's a great idea, or that there aren't more recent questions that are more relevant. You can be sad and crabby all you want--I just don't see the point in un-corpsing seven-year old questions when there are more-recent, more-relevant questions more deserving of attention.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Even on Android.

If you want to stick to Java SE classes, it depends on what you're trying to do.

*Edit: You keep changing your question.* `Date` and `Calendar`.

Comment: Edited question to reflect that.

Comment: @Hounshell It should work on Android, AFAIK, but I haven't done it myself.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on Android, when you add the jar to your project. And it's by far, the best date framework. +1

Comment: What is JSE? (Stupid minimum comment length)

Comment: I agree that Joda-Time is the best solution for date wrangling in Java, in general, but I think it's more important as an API designer to not force unnecessary dependencies on your users (what if their application depends on a different version of Joda-Time than the one your SDK does?).  Although, if Joda-Time provides functionality that is essential to your API then go with it and depend on it explicitly.

Comment: @Hounshell Java Standard Edition. Java.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the "Joda time" part.  Unfortunately I need to stick with core jars shipped with Android, no third-party jars (mostly for the drawbacks that @maerics points out)

Comment: @Hounshell The drawbacks are less interesting than you think since internally your library can do any conversions necessary. Jodatime version differences are a *potential* issue.

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

## Avoid the legacy date-time classes

> So the whole Java Date/Calendar/GregorianCalendar thing is obviously a joke.

Yes, the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are an awful mess. Badly designed, clumsy attempts at improvements, many hacks.

But to be fair, those classes were a valiant effort in addressing a surprisingly tricky topic that the entire information industry has ignored for decades. Based on prior work at [Taligent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taligent) and [IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM), the authors of those classes at least made an attempt where virtually all other programming languages, platforms, and tools take a pass with only the barest minimum of support for date-time handling.

Fortunately we now have the industry-leading *java.time* classes ([JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)) built into Java 8 and later. These were inspired by the success of the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project. Indeed both efforts were led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stephencolebourne).

## java.time

Every single one of your bullet items of complaint is rectified by using java.time instead.

- *99% of Date is deprecated*
  `Instant` replaces `java.util.Date`. AFAIK, nothing is deprecated in java.time in Java 8 & Java 9.
- *Date's Year is offset from 1900*
  Years have sane numbering in java.time, `2018` is the year 2018.
- *Date's Month is zero-indexed while day is one-indexed*
  Months have sane numbering in java.time, 1-12 for January-December. Even better, the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) provides objects to represent each month of the year rather than a mere integer number. So you get valid values, [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and self-documenting code.
- *Dates are mutable*
  Virtually all of java.time is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Any calls to alter some aspect of a java.time object returns a new and distinct object. Even constructors are hidden, with static factory methods used instead.
- *You're supposed to use a Calendar to create a date...*
  `ZonedDateTime` replaces [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).
- *... except you really have to use a GregorianCalendar*
  `ZonedDateTime` replaces [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) too. The java.time framework uses interfaces mostly for internal-use only, encouraging apps to use only the concrete classes. This was a design decision specific to the needs of java.time as a framework and does *not* mean you should the same in your apps.

  - *Do a significant percent of developers want to use a different calendar?*
    Yes. Other calendaring systems are used by many people around the globe. The java.time framework provides for this via the [`Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html) interface and [`AbstractChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/AbstractChronology.html) class. The default chronology is [`IsoChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html) following the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard used generally in the West. In Java 8 & 9, other bundled chronologies include Thai [Buddhist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_calendar), [Hijrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hegira) (Islamic), [Minguo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minguo_calendar) (Taiwan), and [Japanese Imperial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar). Third-parties may implement others. In the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, you’ll find [additional chronologies](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/chrono/package-summary.html) for [Accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar) (proleptic 52/53-week per US IRS Publication 538 and the International Financial Reporting Standards), the British [Julian-Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar#From_Julian_to_Gregorian) cutover, [Coptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_calendar) (Christian Egypt), [Discordian (Erisian)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discordian_calendar), [Ethiopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_calendar), [International Fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Fixed_Calendar) (Cotsworth plan, the Eastman plan), proleptic [Julian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar), [Pax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Calendar), and [Symmetry010](http://individual.utoronto.ca/kalendis/classic.htm) & [Symmetry454](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry454). If only someone would implement the [French Republican Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_Calendar).
- *Calendar.getTime() returns a Date*
  Just use `Instant` as your basic building-block class in java.time, always representing a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. The other types such as `OffsetDateTime` & `ZonedDateTime` can convert back-and-forth with `Instant`.
- *There's no Date math (like how far apart are two dates in years)*
  The java.time classes have many convenient `plus…`/`minus…` methods. Furthermore, java.time provides powerful [`TemporalAduster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) [implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) as well as enabling you to write your own. Also look to the [`ChronoUnit::between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method, such as `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( thisLocalDate , that LocalDate )`.

  - *Messing with milliseconds since epoch doesn't count*
    Look to `Instant::toEpochMilli` and `Instant.ofEpochMilli` if you must use count-from-epoch, but certainly not advisable. Better to use java.time objects and ISO 8601 strings to represent date-time values.
- *You can't chain parts together to get an expression (like the date one year ago today)*
  The java.time classes are definitely designed for call-chaining. Example: `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ).minusYears( 1 ).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.FRANCE )` > `dimanche`. Sometimes appropriate, but don’t go nuts with it — that’s my advice.
- *Probably more stuff*
  Yes many more problems with the old legacy classes. You will find java.time to be a *radical* departure from the old stuff, thoroughly modern and well-designed, a gigantic improvement.

One of the other problem areas is exchanging date-time values with a database. Note that with a JDBC driver compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html) or later ([JSR 221](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221)), you can avoid the date-time related java.sql classes such as [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html) classes. Those old classes are related to the troublesome old legacy classes, and are no longer needed.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

The "right" date type totally depends on your application; however, [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is generally accepted as the replacement for [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) as it provides more functionality (especially regarding extraction of individual date elements like year, month, etc).  In reality, `Date` can be much easier to use for certain situations (and is the one used by Java's own [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) classes), so it's a judgement call.

It's not difficult to convert between the two so I would pick one and stick with it consistently for your API.  If I were to pick one I'd use `Date` because it's the simplest, IMHO.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).