# in java why so much date and time handling function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In java why so much. date and time handling features

eg

java.util , java.sql , calendar , java 8 Date and Time

1. can we use java.util to save in the database. if so then why java.sql introduced
2. while inserting into database should we convert the java.util to java.sql and then save. if so then what will be benefits of it

Comment: Because things improve over time. You should use `java.time.*` for new code. There are varying ways to work with those classes and databases.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/2448440 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8511430/2448440 for `java.util` vs `java.time` and that Joda-Time that everyone was talking about before Java 8. The basic reason for `java.util`s time is "Backwards compatibility"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Use only *java.time* classes.
- Never use date-time classes in the `java.util` and `java.sql`
  packages.

You asked:

> can we use java.util to save in the database. if so then why java.sql introduced

**Use neither.** Both are now outmoded by the *java.time* classes.

And you asked:

> while inserting into database should we convert the java.util to java.sql and then save. if so then what will be benefits of it

**Use neither.** Use only the *java.time* classes.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myOffsetDatetime ) ;
```

…and:

```
OffsetDateTime myOffsetDateTime = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## JSR 310

You asked:

> In java why so much. date and time handling features

The date-time classes in the `java.util` and `java.sql` packages are terribly flawed in their design. They were built decades ago by people who did not understand the complexities and subtleties of date-time handling.

As a whole the information technology industry largely ignored mastering the details of date-time handling in programming. Quite astounding that so many decades passed with no real complete well-designed solution.

In 2014, the [JCP community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process), including Sun/Oracle, voted unanimously to adopt [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). The *java.time* classes became part of Java 8 and later. This framework is now leading the industry.

Adopting JSR 310 meant that the date-time classes in the *java.util* and *java.sql* packages became legacy, supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes. At one point the legacy classes were marked for deprecation, then undone for reasons undisclosed.

## Converting

No need for you to ever use those terrible legacy classes again. Avoid `java.util.Date`, `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `java.sql.Date`, and so on.

If interoperating with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert. Call the new `to…` and `from…` methods added to the old classes.

## Back-ports

For Java 6 & 7, use the back-port library, *ThreeTen-Backport*. Further adapted for early Android (before 26) in the *ThreeTeABP* library.

## JDBC

[JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 and later requires support for exchanging *java.time* objects with the database. Your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) has likely been updated by now.

Learn about methods such as `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

For a moment, that is, for columns of a data type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, support for `java.time.OffsetDateTime` is required. Oddly, support for the more commonly used `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` is not addressed in the JDBC specification. Your driver may or may not support those types. If not, you can easily convert by calling the `at…`, `to…`, and `with…` methods. To make your JDBC code more portable across drivers, exchange only `OffsetDateTime` objects, and convert to/from `Instant`/`ZonedDateTime` as needed.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDate zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

For columns with only a date and a time-of-day but lacking the context of a time zone or an offset-from-UTC (therefore not a moment), that is, for a data-type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

## Evolution

The Joda-Time project is the predecessor to *java.time*. Lessons learned there were used in designing *java.time*. Joda-Time is now in maintenance-mode.

*Joda-Time*, JSR 310, *java.time*, *ThreeTen-Backport*, and *ThreeTen-Extra* are all led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

Comment: _"Oddly, support for the more commonly used Instant and ZonedDateTime is optional."_ The JDBC specification doesn't even mention these types, so support for those types is not optional, supporting those would be non-standard extensions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel if something is not required, and not forbidden, it is optional. And “optional” means other  JDBC drivers may not support those types, so your code will not be portable across drivers. The point of your distinction escapes me.

Comment: In JDBC, optional features are features that are specified by the specification or API doc, but a driver is allowed to not implement an optional feature (and instead throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`, or - for example in the `DatabaseMetaData` - return an empty result set). As JDBC does not define support for `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`, those features are not optional, but non-standard.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Very well, I changed the wording. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

1. `java.util.Date` can't be used to save in database, because there are 3 different data types on database side: `DATE`, `TIME` and `TIMESPAMP`. To reflect these 3 types the `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timespamp` were introduced respectively
2. Java 8 time API is recommended, there's no necessity anymore to use legacy and to deal with a converting between `java.util` and `java.sql`